# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - Host side | Perforce

Tags: localhost, perforce

a non-coder here. I had previously set up Perforce for Unreal Engine purposes on a personal PC locally as the host (with my laptop as client) and after ample of troubleshooting, it worked for a while.
However immediately after a Windows update, relaunching P4Admin and P4V shows me this error:
Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT TCP connect to 1666 failed. connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: WSAECONNREFUSED, **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**.
I have blatantly turned off the Windows Defender Firewall and still the same error. Any idea how to troubleshoot this? Thanks!

[image]

After clicking work disconnect (I noticed the IP is not the same as in cmd->ipconfig->ipv4)

[image])

Comment: If the server is on your desktop PC and you're connecting from your laptop, you should be using the hostname of the desktop PC as part of your P4PORT.  If you specify no hostname, or `localhost`, then your local machine (the laptop) will be treated as the server, which it's not.

Comment: Note that you point your Perforce client at a machine which is not running a Perforce server, that machine will refuse the connection because nothing is listening on that port.  This includes the client machine itself.